# Using onclick for the same tab/window and href for new tab/window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, nunjucks

I am fairly certain this has been asked before but I couldn't find a relevant post after a good amount of searching.

We have a site with product listings on a page. The page has a header, footer and a content section (div) in between. Upon clicking the product listing image, the content section is rendered with a new template and JSON from a REST API. We use jQuery to achieve this. Nunjucks is the templating engine we use.

We basically use a AJAX call to fetch the JSON from the backend and then render the appropriate nunjucks template on the browser with the JSON.

The problem is that this doesn't seem to be able to handle Right-click -> Open in new tab events. Since the new tab has no url, its coming up empty.

How can we handle this scenario where we go with an AJAX DOM update (partial page update) if the link is opened in the same window/tab and load a the full URL if the link is opened in a new window/tab ?

Comment: mmm, tricky, TBO maybe a bit of a cop out but you could add something to the tab that disables right click. In all honesty, with the way technology is going with tablets, macs, phones, right click is a developers method of browsing. If you did want to go down that line then use right click see ('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41488445/using-onclick-for-the-same-tab-window-and-href-for-new-tab-window') and set the href to a actual page with something to say what tab to use.

Comment: Why are you linking to the same question?

Comment: The better solution is what I commented in the duplicate: `<span style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="fetchData()"><img src="..." /></span>`

Comment: But we will need the ability to open in a new tab. This is a general practice this part of the world. Just that it'll be decided by the user. The solution that you suggest @mplungjan will prevent this entirely. Won't work.

Comment: Then rewrite the href

Comment: Well, then thats the question isn't it?  How do we do this rewrite only in the event of opening in a new tab/window. Rewriting href is the easy part.